# Get country name using geolocation with GMAP3.js

Tags: html, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I'm new to the [gmap3](http://gmap3.net) plugin, and reading thru the [documentation](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getgeoloc-54) they show how to get lat an lng using geolocations. is it possible to get the country / state too?

here is the the code they use to get lat and lng

```
$('#test').gmap3({
  getgeoloc:{
    callback : function(latLng){
      if (latLng){
        $(this).gmap3({
          marker:{ 
            latLng:latLng
          },
          map:{
            options:{
              zoom: 5
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From gmap3 plugin docs: [This method](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getaddress-49) allows to retrieve address. And [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=fr#Types) is the Google Maps API documentation page which lists possible fields.